# shiny interacitvity between two output variables

Tags: r, shiny, output, interactive

I struggle at the moment and would require some help.

I have two rhandondables therefore two outputs. Within the render function I make some changes of a dataframe and the user is able to change the dataframe in rhandsonable.

## first table:

```
 output$out <- renderRHandsontable({

if (is.null(input$out)) {
  hot <- rhandsontable(df())
} else {

  hot <- hot_to_r(input$out)
  hot <- rhandsontable(hot)
}


})
```

## second table:

```
output$out2 <- renderRHandsontable({

if (is.null(input$out)) {
  hot <- rhandsontable(df())
} else {

  hot <- hot_to_r(input$out2)
  hot <- rhandsontable(hot)
}

})
```

To make it a little more clear, lets assume the first table (`output$out`) shows a table in absolute numbers and the second (`output$out2`) in percentage. What I would like to point at is that if one updates one table the other table needs to be updated as well. i.e. percentage numbers need to be calculated in absolute numbers and "go back" to a big flat datatable.

Now how do I make this two interactive so that if I update table one the changes will be submitted to table two and the other way around so that always the "most recent" changes are reflected.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

If both your tables share the same underlying data, and you update the underlying data whenever change happens, then it should work. Below is an simple example where both tables will show the same dataset. Update in one will be reflected in the other.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Syncing two RHandontables"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
      ),

      mainPanel(
         rHandsontableOutput("out1"),
         tags$hr(),
         rHandsontableOutput("out2")
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- reactiveValues(data=head(iris))

  output$out1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$data)
  })

  output$out2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$data)
  })

  observeEvent(input$out1, {
    data$data <- hot_to_r(input$out1)
  })

  observeEvent(input$out2, {
    data$data <- hot_to_r(input$out2)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```